# NodeJs require error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, linked-list

I have a nodejs package and i have a linkedList code. I want to include my LinkedList code in my NodeJs js folder but I can't do it. What is the my fault ? 
I want to use it like this

This is my code in my NodeJs folder.(app.js)

```
var KullaniciJS=require('KullaniciLibrary.js');
```

This is my required folder codes.(KullaniciLibrary.js)

```
function Kullanici(KullaniciAdi)
{
    this.KullaniciAdi=KullaniciAdi;
    this.Sonraki=null;
}
function KullaniciListe()
{
    this.Bas=null;
    this.Uzunluk=0;
}
KullaniciListe.prototype.Ekle=function(EklenecekKullaniciAdi)
{
    var Bas=this.Bas;
    if (!Bas) {
        this.Bas = EklenecekKullaniciAdi;
        this.Uzunluk++;

        return EklenecekKullaniciAdi;
    }
    while (Bas.Sonraki!==null) {

        Bas = Bas.Sonraki;
    }

    Bas.Sonraki = EklenecekKullaniciAdi;

    this.Uzunluk++;

    return EklenecekKullaniciAdi;
};
```

Comment: Normally you have to declare what functions you are exporting if you want to create a NPM module. Take a look at this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

Comment: I cant include this js file in my js file ?

Comment: when you want to reference someting on your local machine you use require('./KullaniciLibrary.js') ... notice the ./ before the file. 
If that doesnt work then you you will need to either declare a global(bad idea), using module.exports export an anonymous function, again using module.exports export a named function or export an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to declare inside of your KullaniciLibrary.js file, what you want to export. you do this by adding following line at the end of the file:

```
module.exports = YOUREXPORT;
```

`YOUREXPORT` will probably just be the methodname (or some object).
After that, you wanna import it like this:

```
var KullaniciJS = require('./KullaniciLibrary');
```

Note that you have to prefix the name with `./` and you don't need to define the file-ending.

If you don't prefix the module with `./`, node will search for the module in the `node_modules` folder, instead of the current directory

Comment: When i Run this code block 
var YeniKullanici=new KullaniciJS.Kullanici("ASdf");
console.log(YeniKullanici.KullaniciAdi);
I get this error  TypeError: KullaniciJS.Kullanici is not a function Why ?

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs to require a function from another file you have to export then function.
To export the function use:

`module.export='your function name';`

and to require the function use:

`const variable=require(./filename)`

for more understanding use this link:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html